# android trace file on device

Tags: android, debugging, file, trace

is it possible to create trace file on devices or can I use trace file only on emulator?

Cause I always get `RT-Execption` when I use `Debug.startMethodTracing();`

**Here the Exception:**

```
05-11 09:34:27.687: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5599): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to open trace file '/sdcard/loop_locListener.trace': Permission denied
```

thanks

Comment: How are you starting method tracing. On what device ? /sdcard is not standart mount point for your sdcard

Comment: I tried on Samsung Galaxytab and Nexus S. 

I use startMethodTracing for analyse whats going on in my Looper:

`public void run() {
  Looper.prepare(); 
  mHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {}
  };
  Debug.startMethodTracing();
  Looper.loop();
  Debug.stopMethodTracing();
}`

Comment: Ok, found the answer for my problem by myself.

I just forget to set android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in manifest.